# How to solve this system of three equations quickly and efficiently?

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, arithmetic

I have this system of equations:

$
s_{13}=0.4 s_{13}+0.2 s_{23}+0.1 s_{33}
$

$
s_{23}=0.1 s_{13}+0.5 s_{23}+0.2 s_{33}
$

$
s_{33}=1+0.3 s_{13}+0.4 s_{23}+0.2 s_{33} 
$

I know how to solve a system of equations with 2 unknowns and 2 equatons by hand with substitution. With a 3x3 system this becomes more difficult. Normally I solve larger systems with software.

Is there a different method by which I can solve this by hand efficiently?

Comment: use linear combinations of rows to eliminate the same variable from all equations, getting 2 eqns in 2 var

Comment: @gt6989b could you please show me part of the solution? I'm not really sure what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, lets rename $s_{13}=s, s_{23}=t, s_{33} = u$, move all variables to the right and constants to the left to get
$$
\begin{split}
 0 &= -0.6s &+ 0.2t &+ 0.1u\\
 0 &=  0.1s &- 0.5t &+ 0.2u\\
-1 &=  0.3s &+ 0.4t &- 0.8u
\end{split}
$$
Note that if we double the first row and subtract from the second one, this will eliminate $u$. Similarly, if we quadruple the second one and add to the third one, that will also eliminate $u$, resulting in 2 equations by 2 unknowns that you know how to solve.

Once you solve for $s$ and $t$, plug into any of these equations to find $u$.